# Align two image views in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a two `UIImageView` in my xib file. Both start at same origin, and are of same dimension. When I run the code I expect them to be on top of each other, but one seems to be off. Look at the screenshot. What I am doing wrong here ?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Both images are same? If different are they are of same size? Can you add the code that you have used for your image view?

Comment: can one of them of mode be "scale to fit" and others' can be "aspect fit"?

Comment: I was doing all the work in xib file. I did not add code for uiimageviews

Answer (score 1):

Are they both in the same view? My guess is that they are in different views. Why? Because the offset looks like it is identical to the height of the navigation bar.

Remember that the origin is relative to the view, not the screen.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, it seems that you have two `UIImageView`s with different `autoresizingMask`s.

In IB, select each image view in turn, go to the attribute inspector and check if you have the same setting under "View -> Mode". It seems the top image is "Aspect Fit", while the bottom one is "Scale To Fill".

Answer (score 0):

i dont know how you getting like this even though you  have given same dimension for imageview
so please check your dimension once again